# How to include SID in the ID Token?

Tags: spring-security, spring-authorization-server

SID is needed to logout user from Spring OAuth Server, how do you return the sid claim in the ID Token?

I upgraded to the latest unreleased Spring security and OAuth server and configured the post redirect uri. When I tried to logout it said that the SID parameter is missing. Am not seeing any SID value return when I authenticate, thought it would be automatically included in the ID token that was generated.

Comment: The [demo sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples#demo-sample) demonstrates this. You can base your configuration on the sample.

Comment: I have the  same issue

Answer (score 2):

It is added automatically when OpenID Connect 1.0 is enabled as demonstrated in the [Getting Started](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html#defining-required-components) example. The example also demonstrates setting `postLogoutRedirectUri`.

**Note:** You need to make sure that you are requesting the `openid` scope during authorization, because this feature requires that you are using OpenID Connect to log in.

Comment: OpenID Connect 1.0 is enabled and I also request `openid` scope. I have try to mimic the demo  `AuthorizationServerConfig` & `DefaultSecurityConfig` as much as possible. Only difference I require PKCE and don't require consent

Comment: Do you have a sample `id_token` (signed by a test key) handy that can be loaded into jwt.io for inspection?

Comment: Also, what version are you using? The `sid` claim and OIDC Logout is a new feature in 1.1.0.

Comment: I am using version 1.1.0 with spring boot 3.10.0-RC2 and Spring security 6.10.0

Comment: I will share the `id_token` on Github, it exceed the max allowed characters

Comment: Here's a standalone project to try: https://github.com/sjohnr/sas-native-demo/tree/so-76259728

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253705/discussion-between-steve-riesenberg-and-ramon10).

Comment: I had a `OAuth2AuthorizationService` `bean` configured. Once removed the issue was resolved. Thanks for the assistance

Comment: Where do you save authorization details in production.

Comment: You would provide a `OAuth2AuthorizationService` bean, such as `JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService`.

Comment: I save my data in a Postgres database and it works without configuring the `OAuth2AuthorizationService bean`

Comment: Without configuring the bean, you are using the default which is an `InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizationService` which (as the name implies) saves authorizations in-memory.